# Bi-directional association

Tags: java, uml, polymorphic-associations, bidirectional

The concept with association and also how it relates to the UML design. I would appreciate if some expert could give me an idea or code design relate to the UML picture attached.

[image: There are 3 differently designed UML as seen below]

Thanks in adv!!!

```java
public class Borrower {
    private String name;

    public Borrower() {
        Equipment[] tester = new Equipment[5];
        tester[0] = new Equipment(this);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Equipment {
    Borrower[] person = new Borrower[10];

    public Equipment(Borrower b) {
        person[0] = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is

```
public class Loan {
    private final Date date;
    private final Borrower borrower;
    private final Equipment equipment;

    Loan(Borrower borrower, Equipment equipment, Date date) {
        this.borrower = borrower;
        this.equipment = equipment;
        this.date = date;
    }
}

public class Borrower {
    private String name;
    private final List<Loan> loans = new ArrayList<>();

    public Borrower(String name, Equipment equipment, Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        borrow(equipment, date);
    }

    public void borrow(Equipment equipment, Date date) {
        Loan loan = new Loan(this, equipment, date);
        loans.add(loan);
        equipment.addLoan(loan);
    }
}

public class Equipment {
    private final List<Loan> loans = new ArrayList<>();

    void addLoan(Loan loan) {
        loans.add(loan);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a few words of explanation. That would make me up-vote your answer :-)

Comment: which diagram are you referring this?

Comment: @EnHuiLim 2nd or 3rd.

Comment: @saka1029 i dont know if the code provided would be referring to the second diagram. But I wish to analyse how the 2nd UML and 3rd UML works. And also given case study which is the best to format to apply to the UML design.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd and the 3rd representations are alternatives ways to show the same thing. It is called association class. Here `Loan` is the association class and it acts as a link between the two classes it connects, thereby adding some additional attributes/operations. An association class always represents a 1-m-n-1 relation.

The first diagramming example is a more business oriented representation. It uses a common-place label with triangle that shows the order of reading. It leaves open how this shall be implemented. An association class would be a common way to do that. But you could as well hold an array of `Equipment` inside `Borrower`. You may notice that here the date of borrowing is not present.